# How to substract a layer from another in Photoshop CS6

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have basically a layer in Photoshop CS6 containing an "email" symbol image. It has a transparent background, and just a red email symbol on top:

[image: screenshot]

Now I would like to subtract that red stuff to a white ellipse to get a white ellipse with a transparent email symbol in it.

I have tried creating another layer with an ellipse and searched all over Google for "how can I subtract two different layers" or whatever, none of my tries brought what I want :(

I don't if what I'm saying is precise enough or appropriate, first time here. Don't hesitate to ask if I forgot something!

Thanks for the help,

Florian

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it...

Create a new document with your white ellipse. Then, in your document with the red email icon, from the layers list select to duplicate that layer into the new document with the ellipse. Transform > scale if you need to and position it where you need it to be within the ellipse. Then, with the red email icon layer selected, click 'select' in the top menu, then click 'Colour Range'... click anywhere on the red, click OK, then... change to your ellipse layer and hit the delete button. Hide your red email icon and what you should now see is your white ellipse with a transparent email icon in it.

I think that should get you the result you want.

Del.